# add elements to object array

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

This must be really simple but just not getting my syntax right here. let's say we have  classes like two below:

```
class Student
{
    Subject[] subjects;
}

class Subject
{
    string Name;
    string referenceBook;
}
```

Here is my code:

```
Student univStudent = new Student();
```

Now, I want to add subjects here but not able to do something like

```
univStudent.subjects.add(new Subject{....});
```

How do i add items to this object array?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can try

```cs
Subject[] subjects = new Subject[2];
subjects[0] = new Subject{....};
subjects[1] = new Subject{....};
```

alternatively you can use List

```cs
List<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>();
subjects.Add(new Subject{....});
subjects.Add(new Subject{....});
// Then you can convert the List to Array like below:
Subject[] arraySubjects = subjects.ToArray<Subject>()
```

Comment: I used the 2nd way and did a .ToArray<Subject>()

Comment: `subjects.add` may need to be `subjects.Add`

Answer (score 19):

You can use class System.Array for add new element:

```
Array.Resize(ref objArray, objArray.Length + 1);
objArray[objArray.Length - 1] = new Someobject();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't. However, you can replace the array with a new one which contains the extra element.

But it is easier and gives better performance to use an `List<T>` (uses interface `IList`) for this. `List<T>` does not resize the array every time you add an item - instead it doubles it when needed.

Try:

```
class Student
{
    IList<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>();
}

class Subject
{
    string Name;
    string referenceBook;
}
```

Now you can say:

```
someStudent.subjects.Add(new Subject());
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can, use a `List<Subject>` instead of `Subject[]`... this will let you do `Student.Subject.Add(new Subject())`.  If that is not possible, you'll have to resize your array... look at Array.Resize() at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but came across it looking for a simpler way, and this is how i do it, just create a new list of the same object and add it to the one you want to use e.g.

```
Subject[] subjectsList = {new Subject1{....}, new Subject2{....}, new Subject3{....}} 
univStudent.subjects = subjectsList ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it `ToList()`, add and then convert it back `ToArray()`.

```
var subjectList = univStudent.subjects.ToList();
subjectList.Add(new Subject());
univStudent.subjects = subjectList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list as follows.

```
List<Subject> allDestek = new List<Subject>() {
   new Subject(){ ID = 1, Name = "aaaa"},
   new Subject(){ ID = 2, Name = "bbbb"},
   new Subject(){ ID = 2, Name = "cccc"},
   new Subject(){ ID = 2, Name = "dddd"}
 };

 allSubject.ToArray()
```

If data is coming from somewhere (EF,SQL), you can add it in a table as follows.

```
Stutent[] allStudent = _dataRepository.Subjectes.ToArray();
```